# Appending decimal numbers in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm

I have numbers in the registers. How can I append values in a single register.

eg.

```
$t0 has value 1
$t1 has value 2

I want to form value 12.
```

Those register values can be inputed by UART tool.
so I can't apply mathematics 1*10+2.

```
$t0 has value 11
$t1 has value 4
The value should be 114.
```

What is the standard way of forming values in assembly in PLP. I am using ARM architecture.

Comment: Why can't you “apply mathematics?” Because that's how you do this.

Comment: Quite unusual request for me, usually such values have fixed range, and the appending is done to respect those ranges, so then `114` can be split back into `11` and `4` (when you know, that first value has two digits 0-99, and second has one digit 0-9). In your universal way you can't tell if it was 11|4, or 1|14, at source. Are you sure you want them concatenated as string? And what will you do then? If you want just output them as string, then convert both numbers to string first, and concatenate strings. Otherwise some computing will be involved (figuring out num of digits and *10^n then).

Comment: Either they are numbers, in which case such "concatenation" is only valid for representations in one particular base, and can _always_ be done via arithmetic in that base; or it's simply a string concatenation problem which has nothing to do with "numbers" other than happening to involve characters commonly used to represent digits. Pick one or the other, because it can't be both. (Side note: AFAIK the Parliamentary Labour Party doesn't have any particular standard programming practices, but maybe add some embarrassing infighting and sit on the floor of a train carriage, just in case).